# Are auto-responses from STOP keywords in MobileConnect charged to the business that owns the SFMC Account?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

just like the SMS cost of MobileConnect, is the auto responses from STOP and Opt-In keywords also cost?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it answered your question ^^ It can help someone else in the future..

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why it should not be charged.

Here is what I've found in the doc:

> Customer will be charged for all outbound, mobile terminated (MT) SMS
> messages, whether delivered or undelivered.

Source: [SMS/ MMS Messages](https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/assets/pdf/misc/sms-mms-messages-september-1-2022.pdf)